# Android ListView ArrayAdapter getting data from host activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` which I use to populate a `ListView` in an `Activity`. The logic in the `getView` method of my `ArrayAdapter` requires an additional piece of information which is held in an instance variable in the *host* `Activity`. What's the best way of accessing this variable from within the `getView` method of my `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: use a SimpleCursorAdapter + ContentProvider

Comment: You will have to pass that information also in the constructor of your Custom Array Adapter from the host activity.

Comment: Prankul how would I pass this in the constructor of the Custom Array Adapter? That's exactly what I would like to do but I don't know how to access that activity class variable from the constructor of the Array Adapter ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

String addInfo;
public CustomArrayAdapter(String additionalInfo)
{
addInfo=additionalInfo;
}

}
```

when creating object for arrayadapter, use it like below

```
CustomArrayAdapter custAdapter=new CustomArrayAdapter("Additional Info");
```